# Import python module from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm using Python 3.9x. As I have a code structure like:

```
main.py
|--moduleA
    |--A.py
|--moduleB
    |--B.py
```

In B.py, it imports A.py. Now I want test B.py, so I run B.py as a single python file. Then what how should import A in B.py?
Note: I tried using `sys.path.append('../')` or `from ..moduelA` neither works. Please tell me what wrong was it? Thank you.

Comment: Have you included `__init__.py` in moduleA and moduleB? This makes them be considered packages.

Comment: Yes I did. Still not working

Comment: What happens if you run B.py as a module i.e `python3.9 -m moduleB.B`? I tried recreating your directory structure, and this worked with `from moduleA import A`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would import A.py like this.

```
import moduleA.A
```

Comment: from B.py, are you sure? I got 'No module named moduleA'